# Where can I download the SQL Server 2008 SMO dlls

Tags: sql-server, dll, smo

I had the SQL Server 2008 dlls, and I installed SQL Server 2008R2 Feature Pack. Rather than putting them in `Program Files/105/SDK`, it put them in `Program Files/100/SDK` and overwrote my 2008 SMO dlls.

There are some slight differences, and I need to get the 2008 dlls, at least temporarily, but I cannot find where to get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6375). This is for SQL 2008 SP2 so hopefully should have what you're after

HTH, Nathan

Comment: Thanks. I can never seem to find the Microsoft download that I want.

Comment: No probs, like a needle in a haystack sometimes...Good luck with getting those SMO assemblies :-)

Comment: For 2012 SP1, [go here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35580)

Answer (score 0):

The link provided in 2013 doesn't seem to work anymore.

I did a search and found it here:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 4 Feature Pack:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44277